# Closure Compiler modifying end bracket in string

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure

I try to run the following Javascript code through closure compiler:

```
var firstRun = eval("<?--#exec cmd_argument='command'-->");
```

And it comes out as:

```
var a=eval(" <?--#exec cmd_argument='command'--\x3e")
```

Since it is an SSI command I need i to not convert `>` to `\x3e`. I have tried using `--charset=utf-8` and `US-ascii` as input to Closure Compiler. I have also tried using `\u003e` in the string. Whatever I do it outputs `>` as `\x3e`, which seems very odd, since it does not do the same to <.

The input command to closure compiler I use is:

```
java -jar compiler.jar --js file.js --js_output_file newfile.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if there is a compiler option to avoid that happening, my view is that this is not a good practice, as you are relying on how precisely the compiler will output something (i.e. your SSI string in this case) that can have many different representations (as you can see the original string is changed).

The compiler does this to avoid the string `-->` that will end an HTML comment in case it's embedded in HTML code. It used to be common practice to wrap JavaScript in an HTML comment to avoid error in browsers that didn't support JavaScript.

---

Possible solution: can you separately include your SSI string so that it will not go through the compilation process? That way you can guarantee it's not going to be affected by the compiler.

This could be done either by including the SSI string in another **uncompiled** JS file or by prepending the **uncompiled** SSI string in the **compiled** JS output. Something like this:

```
var MY_GLOBAL_SSI_STRING = "<?--#exec cmd_argument='command'-->";
// compiled code follows...
```

Then you can refer to MY_GLOBAL_SSI_STRING from your (to be compiled) code like this:

```
var firstRun = eval(goog.global['MY_GLOBAL_SSI_STRING']);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: It is actually trying to avoid --> that will end a HTML comment.  It used to be common practice to wrap javascript in an HTML comment to avoid error in browsers that didn't support JavaScript.   This isn't a problem if your load the script as a separate resource but it doesn't if you inline the script into your HTML.

Comment: Ah, so that's the reason. I haven't checked if this would happen to every ">" within a string. Perhaps you should edit my answer to point this out. Thanks!

Comment: It should only be with "-->" not every ">"

Comment: You could also use something like `'--' + String.fromCharCode(62)` as I don't believe the compiler will optimize that.